# What is between C# and java Enum Constructor

Tags: java, c#

I have a next code in C#:

```
  public CryptoTimeInForce? TimeInForce ;


 public void metod(SomeClass baseTrade){
this.TimeInForce = new CryptoTimeInForce?(baseTrade.TimeInForce);
}
```

CryptoTimeInForce is Enum

```
public enum CryptoTimeInForce : byte
{
 ///values
}
```

How I can create enum in java to provide the same logic like in C# code?
Enum in java cant be instantiated and i cant repeat same code in java.
Is there any alternatives?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are insantiating enums like this in the first place?

Comment: You need to update or correct your C# sample - enums in C# have no constructors.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Actually you can instantiate them this way in C# ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aNrZH5))

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, but you're instantiating System.Nullable, not the enum directly.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Yes, that's why I said it was possible...

Answer (score 1):

In java, you get the '?' part for free, since java enums are objects, so they are always nullable.

In java, you cannot have an `enum` derive from `byte`, but that should not matter, it is just a performance optimization.

There are many other differences between java enums and C# enums, but absolutely none that would be a problem for what you are trying to do, from the code you have shown us.

Also, as DavidG comment says, it is entirely pointless to be instantiating an enum in C#, so the fact that you cannot instantiate an enum in java should be irrelevant. Enums are not meant to be instantiated, they are just constants.